# Attaching Event Handlers to JQuery-generated DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm pulling some data from an external API and then displaying it in a dashboard page. To do this, I'm generating DOM elements once I've processed the data, like so:

```
for(var key in companies) {
    $(document.createElement("span"))
      .attr({ id: key })
      .appendTo($("#someDiv"))
      .click(function() {
          alert(key);
      });
      $("#"+key).html("<b>" + key + "</b>: $"+companies[key]+"<br>");
  }
```

However, when I click on any of the newly generated `span` elements, I get an alert with the last value in `companies`. For example, if I had declared:

```
var companies = {
    "Google": 3,
    "Apple": 4
};
```

then clicking on both the Google `span` and the Apple `span` would alert `4`. My desired behavior is clicking on the Google `span` to alert `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the `key` value with a closure, since the loop will have finished by the time the `click` handler actually executes. Try this:

```
.click((function() {
    return function () {
        alert(key);
    };
})());
```

Or, you can just `alert` its `id`, since that's what you set it as:

```
.click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Why does returning a function that calls `alert(key)` yield different behavior than just calling `alert(key)`?

Comment: It's a closure, keeping the value of the key within the function, as key will change for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:-

Attach the event handler using event delagtion with `on()` just once. (See the class added `compName`). and just using its `id`.

See Delegated event handler reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If somediv already exist in DOM then you can just use `$('#someDiv').on('click','.compName',function(){...`

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.compName',function(){ 
//.....
   alert(this.id);
//....
});
....
for(var key in companies) {
    $(document.createElement("span"))
      .attr({ id: key, 'class':'compName' }).html("<b>" + key + "</b>: $"+companies[key]+"    
      <br>").html("<b>" + key + "</b>: $"+companies[key]+"<br>").
      .appendTo($("#someDiv"));

  }
//...
})
```

Comment: No reason to use `document` for the delegated event container - all the elements are appended to `#someDiv`, so I think that's safe to use

Comment: Why on earth would you use event delegation when you're creating the element on the next line ?

Comment: @adeneo why would you want to attach event to each element, instead yu could just attach to one parent and have it delegated.

Comment: It seems you are under the impression that delegated event handlers are always more efficient than regular event handlers, and if that's the case, why don't we just have one single click handler on the document level and sort thru the elements there, and it's even always available, so no more DOM ready crap or elements that are'nt there? Sometimes event delegation is neccessary for elements that will be created later, and sometimes it's more efficient delegating the event instead of using a bunch of event handlers, most of the time, regular event handlers are the way to go.

Comment: Yes exactly thats my point here this element is getting created and appended dynamically into DOM.

Comment: Yeah, but you are creating it on the next line, it's not something that's unpredictable, like with ajax etc ?

Comment: DOnt know where he is creating the elements right... this event delegation part is just another section... ALso you dont need to attach it to document you can do it on the parent which exists already.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variable key gets changed before you call the function. You need a closure around it to prevent it from modified by the outer code:

```
for(var key in companies) {
    $(document.createElement("span"))
      .attr({ id: key })
      .appendTo($("#someDiv"))
      .click((function(privatekey) {
          return function(){
              alert(privatekey);
              };
      })(key));
      $("#"+key).html("<b>" + key + "</b>: $"+companies[key]+"<br>");
  }
```